# Todo list with classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I am doing this challenge but I am stuck on something which couldn't figure out so far. I also found a topic opened very similar to this one but it is at the same stage where I am now and the "rspec" it says that there's still something wrong with my code.

Below there's the challenge:

Write a program that keeps a list of todos. It should:

- Have two classes:

  - `Todo`

    - Has two methods:
    - `initialize`: Creates a new todo object. Takes a string as a
      parameter and stores it on the todo object.
    - `text`: Takes no parameters. Returns the string that was
      stored when the todo object was created.
  - `TodoList`

    - Has three methods:
    - `initialize`: Creates a new todo list object. Takes no parameters.
    - `add`: Takes a todo object as a parameter.  Stores it on the
      todo list object.
    - `print`: Takes no parameters.  Creates a string of all the
      stored todos, one per line.  Each line should start with a
      `*`.  `puts`es the string.
      e.g.

      - get milk
      - get the papers

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
class Todo
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def text
    @string
  end
end

class TodoList
  def initialize
    @todolist = []
  end

  def add(todo)
    @todolist << Todo.new(todo)
  end

  def print
    @todolist.each do |item|
    puts "* get #{item.text}"
  end
 end
end
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

```
Failure/Error: expect { todo_list.print }.to output("* get 
milk\n").to_stdout

   expected block to output "* get milk\n" to stdout, but output "* get #<Todo:0x007f8766831f90>\n"
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -* get milk
   +* get #<Todo:0x007f8766831f90>

 # ./spec/question_1_spec.rb:43:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Here is the spec code:

```
 describe "Q1. Todo list" do
   describe Todo do
    describe "creating a new Todo" do
     it "creates a new todo object" do
      expect(Todo.new("get milk")).to be_instance_of Todo
     end
   end

describe "getting text on todo" do
  it "returns text stored on todo" do
    expect(Todo.new("get milk").text).to eq("get milk")
  end
end
end

describe TodoList do
  describe "creating a TodoList" do
    it "creates a new todo list object" do
     expect(TodoList.new).to be_instance_of TodoList
   end
 end

describe "adding todos" do
  let(:todo) { Todo.new("get milk") }
  let(:todo_list) { TodoList.new }

   it "adds a todo without raising an error" do
    expect { todo_list.add(todo) }.to_not raise_error
   end
  end

describe "printing todos" do
  let(:todo) { Todo.new("get milk") }
  let(:todo_list) { TodoList.new }

  context "one todo" do
    it "prints a single todo with a bullet point" do
      todo_list.add(todo)

      expect { todo_list.print }.to output("* get milk\n").to_stdout
    end
  end

  context "many todos" do
    let(:todo_1) { Todo.new("get milk") }
    let(:todo_2) { Todo.new("get the paper") }
    let(:todo_3) { Todo.new("get orange juice") }
    let(:todo_list) { TodoList.new }

    let(:expected_output) { ["* get milk",
                            "* get the paper",
                            "* get orange juice"].join("\n") +
                           "\n" }

    it "prints the todos, separated by newlines" do
      todo_list.add(todo_1)
      todo_list.add(todo_2)
      todo_list.add(todo_3)

      expect { todo_list.print }.to output(expected_output).to_stdout
    end
  end
end
end
```

Comment: I am sure I am doing something wrong, probably the way I want to solve the problem is not the one that the problem is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by hand what rspec is doing:

```
todo = Todo.new("get milk")
todo_list = TodoList.new
todo_list.add(todo)
todo_list.print
#=> * #<Todo:0x007fb3e40f1b40>
```

It happens that the print method is printing the content of the `@todolist` array.
What's in `@todolist`?
Looking at the `add` method:

```
@todolist << Todo.new(todo)
```

So, befere to add the `Todo` object to the array it first create a new `Todo` instance passing `Todo` object received as parameter. Kinda nesting. Like calling:

```
todo2 = Todo.new("get milk")
todo3 = Todo.new(todo2)
puts todo3 #=> #<Todo:0x007fe20a02c968>
```

**Solve by changing the metod `add` this way:**

```
def add(todo)
  @todolist << todo
end
```

Now it should work:

```
todo = Todo.new("get milk")
todo_list = TodoList.new
todo_list.add(todo)
todo_list.print
#=> * get milk
```